# SQL statement to count corresponding entries while having a strict sequence (logical)

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to aggregate the number of (identical) parts in my production plan while preserving the sequence.

My table looks like this:

```
-------------------------------------------------
|Part Number | Production Sequence Number | .... |
-------------------------------------------------
|           1|                           1| .... |
--------------------------------------------------
|           1|                           2| .... |
--------------------------------------------------
|           2|                           3| .... |
--------------------------------------------------
|           2|                           4| .... |
--------------------------------------------------
|           1|                           5| .... |
--------------------------------------------------
```

And I need to count the amount of same parts in a row:

Expected result:

```
-------------------------------------------------
|Part Number | Nr of pieces in a row      | .... |
-------------------------------------------------
|           1|                           2| .... |
-------------------------------------------------
|           2|                           2| .... |
-------------------------------------------------
|           1|                           1| .... |
-------------------------------------------------
```

Can this be done by only unsing SQL (MySQL)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use variable to emulate numbers and then perform `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT id, COUNT(*)
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        @row_number:=CASE
            WHEN @seq_num = id THEN @row_number
            ELSE @row_number + 1
        END AS num,
        @seq_num:=id as id,
        seq_num
    FROM tab, (SELECT @row_number:=0, @seq_num := 1) t
    ORDER BY seq_num
) t
GROUP BY num, id
```

[demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=49042a511668be2fa68d531e06168d50)

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky in MySQL.  One method is to use a correlated subquery to define the groups.  You can define the groups by counting the number of part numbers before the current row that are *different* from the part number on that row.  This uniquely identifies the groups:

```
select partnum, count(*)
from (select t.*,
             (select count(*)
              from t t2
              where t2.seqnum < t.seqnum and
                    t2.partnum <> t.partnum
             ) as grp
      from t
     ) t
group by partnum, grp;
```

I should note that you would use window functions in most databases for this purpose.  The correlated subquery is used because MySQL lacks this important functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I like this question it make me search and discover new things, I already have the idea I just want to make it real, about the idea is simple :

- Combine all the rows (`11221`)
- Separate each difference of numbers with a separator (`11,22,1`)
- Split with this separator (`[11, 22, 1]`)
- Count the length of each part (`2,2,1`)

PostgreSQL solution:

I already solved the problem in PostgreSQL i think there are a way to translate it to MySQL Syntax

```
SELECT
   SUBSTRING(regexp_split_to_table(regexp_replace(array_to_string(array_agg(part), ''), '((\d)\2+)', '\1,', 'g'), ','), 1, 1) as part_number,
   length(regexp_split_to_table(regexp_replace(array_to_string(array_agg(part), ''), '((\d)\2+)', '\1,', 'g'), ',')) as production_sequence_number 
FROM
   mytable
```

Output

[image: result]